# Blame on an earlier version of a file in a different location

Tags: git, blame

At one point my git repository had its paths reorganized.

I often want to do a blame on a file at a revision before the move.

What's the git blame incantation to blame a file that doesn't exist in the current repository?

I tried:

```
> git blame new/path/to/file old_rev
fatal: no such path ... in old_rev

> git blame old/path/to/file old_rev
fatal: cannot stat path ... in old_rev

> git blame old_rev:old/path/to/file old_rev
fatal: cannot stat path ... in old_rev
```

Clearly I could just check out old_rev and blame the appropriate path, but I'd rather avoid that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `git blame --follow` to make blame follow your renames.

I also see your parameters are in the wrong order, try the following:

```
git blame old_rev -- old/path/to/file
```

Comment: Either order works if the file in question hasn't moved, at least in recent git versions. As it turns out, I normally use the right order, but when I was constructing the question I cut and pasted from the wrong set of attempts. Anyway, thanks for the magic of the -- delimiter, that's what I was missing!